# How to combine tkinter and turtle?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I have a part of codes like this

```
import turtle
turtle.bgcolor("green")
draw = turtle.Turtle()
draw.speed(1000000)
draw.hideturtle()
draw.pensize(3)
draw.color("white")

def Board (a, x, y, size):
    draw.pu()
    draw.goto(x, y)
    draw.pd()
    for i in range (0, 4):
        draw.forward(size)
        draw.right(90)

x =-40
y = -40
size = 40
for i in range (0, 10):
    for j in range (0, 10):
         Board (draw, x + j*size, y + i*size, size)

turtle.done()
```

And like this

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
window = tkinter.Tk()
def Button_click ():
   tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Game", "Tic Tac Toe")

button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Play!", command = Button_click)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Since I'm trying to create a window with a button to enter the TicTacToe game (I haven't finished the rest, just only the board). Is there any way that I can do to combine both turtle and tkinter?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Python turtle operates in two modes, *standalone* and *embedded* in a larger tkinter program.  Instead of `Turtle` and `Screen`, when using turtle embedded, you work with `RawTurtle`, `TurtleScreen` and optionally `ScrolledCanvas`.  You build your tkinter interface as needed, using a Canvas to contain your turtle graphics.  You can find examples of embedding turtle in tkinter by searching SO for `RawTurtle`.

[Here's an example of the same code written both *embedded* and *standalone*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639041/5771269).

Answer (score 1):

I was playing with your code while cdlane was answering your question! As cdlane said I replaced "turtle" with "RawTurtle" and put your button on the same window as the canvas. I prefer using grid than pack when placing things because I feel like I have more control.

```
import tkinter
import turtle
import tkinter.messagebox

window = tkinter.Tk()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = window, width = 800, height = 800)
canvas.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=0, column=0, rowspan=10, columnspan=10) # , sticky='nsew')
#draw = turtle.Turtle()
draw = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

def Board(a, x, y, size):
    #draw.pu()
    draw.penup()
    draw.goto(x,y)
    #draw.pd()
    draw.pendown()
    for i in range (0, 4):
        draw.forward(size)
        draw.right(90)

def Board2():
    x =-40
    y = -40
    size = 40
    for i in range (0, 10):
        for j in range (0, 10):
            Board(draw, x + j*size, y + i*size, size)

def Button_click ():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Game", "Tic Tac Toe")

#button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Play!", command = Button_click)
#button = Tk.Button(window, text = "Play!", command = Button_click)
#button.pack()
#
Play_Button = tkinter.Button(master = window, text ="Play!", command = Button_click)
Play_Button.config(bg="cyan",fg="black")
Play_Button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=0, column=11, sticky='nsew')

Board_Button = tkinter.Button(master = window, text ="Draw_Board", command = Board2)
Board_Button.config(bg="cyan",fg="black")
Board_Button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=1, column=11, sticky='nsew')
#
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i see but what if i have created a library (like this one) :

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint

class Toit(Turtle):

    def __init__(self,x,y,deg):
        super().__init__()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.speed(0)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.deg = deg

    def draw_toit(self, model=int,ind=float):
        self.pu()
        self.goto(self.x,self.y)
        self.setheading(self.deg)

        if model is None:
            mod = randint(1, 3)
        else:
            mod = model

        self.pendown()

        if mod == 2:
            self.pensize(2)
            self.fillcolor('#000000')
            self.begin_fill()
            self.left(25)
            for i in range(2):
                self.forward(78*ind)
                self.right(50)
            self.end_fill()

        elif mod == 3:
            self.pensize(2)
            self.fillcolor('#000000')
            self.begin_fill()
            for i in range(2):
                self.forward(160*ind)
                self.circle(2*ind, 180)
            self.end_fill()

        elif mod == 1:
            self.pensize(2)
            self.fillcolor('#000000')
            self.begin_fill()
            for i in range(2):
                self.forward(140*ind)
                self.circle(2*ind, 180)
            self.end_fill()

        self.penup()
        self.goto(self.x,self.y)
        self.setheading(self.deg)
```

And I want to draw this "toit" into a tkinter window in a separate program. How is it possible?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).