# Python Turtle Objects in conjuction with tkinter is it possible?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I'm having an issue when I run my main.py, it shows two screens. I know it's because I'm calling an object, just not sure if it's possible to use objects and have it show up on the tkinter window.

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import TurtleScreen
from createDotTest import Dot
top = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(top, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas) 
screen.tracer(0)

list_of_points = []
list_of_lines = []

for x in range(100):
    dot = Dot()
    list_of_points.append(dot)

screen.mainloop()
```

**createDotTest.py**

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random

class Dot(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        x_pos = random.randint(-280, 280)
        y_pos = random.randint(-280, 280)
        self.shapesize(.2,.2)
        self.penup()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.goto(x_pos, y_pos)
        self.stamp()
```

I tried also replacing Turtle as TurtleRaw in the **createDotTest.py** but I get

```
raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad canvas argument %s" % canvas)
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad canvas argument None
```

Answer (score 1):

This question looks similar to [Combine tkinter and turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246872/how-to-combine-tkinter-and-turtle)

I am not sure but this may help you

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at that. The issue is, I have two separate python files. Maybe I could try combining them, but I wanted to keep main.py it's own thing.

Comment: Could you append the solution from within the link to this answer. The content in the links does change and we dont trust even other SO links here. Thanks!